# How do I override a decorated method in Python?

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I want to extend the following Python class, which includes a decorator that I don't know much about:

```
from somewhere import some_decorator

class One(object):
    @some_decorator
    def some_method(self):
        do_something()
```

Should I decorate the overridden method or not?  In other words, can I safely do:

```
class Two(One):
    def some_method(self):
        super(Two, self).some_method()
```

Or do I need to do:

```
class Two(One):
    @some_decorator
    def some_method(self):
        super(Two, self).some_method()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember what the `@decorator` syntax does:

```
@decorator
def foo():
    print "foo"
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
def foo():
    print "foo"
foo = decorator(foo)
```

Thus, the undecorated function is no longer callable by its name after it has been decorated because its name has been assigned to something else.

This means that when you call `super(Two, self).some_method()` in the child class, then the decorated function `some_method` in the parent will be called.

Knowing whether or not you also need to decorate the child overridden method entirely depends on what you want to do and what the decorator does. But know that if you call `super(Two, self).some_method()`, then you will call the decorated function.

Answer (score 11):

For those wondering about edge cases, here is an example:

```py
import functools


def print_hi(func):
    """Decorate a function to print stuff."""

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_print_hi(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"hello and up next: calling {func.__qualname__}")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_print_hi


class Foo:
    @print_hi
    def gets_overridden(self) -> None:
        print(f"Foo.gets_overridden")


class DFooNoRedecorate(Foo):
    def gets_overridden(self) -> None:
        """Overridden but didn't re-decorate."""
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.gets_overridden")


class DFooRedecorate(Foo):
    @print_hi
    def gets_overridden(self) -> None:
        """Overridden and re-decorated."""
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.gets_overridden")


class DFooNoRedecorateWithSuperCall(Foo):
    def gets_overridden(self) -> None:
        """Overridden but didn't re-decorate, with super call."""
        super().gets_overridden()
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.gets_overridden")


class DFooRedecorateWithSuperCall(Foo):
    @print_hi
    def gets_overridden(self) -> None:
        """Overridden and re-decorated, with super call."""
        super().gets_overridden()
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.gets_overridden")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("---")
    # Decorator doesn't happen when not explicitly called out in subclass
    DFooNoRedecorate().gets_overridden()
    print("---")
    # Decorator does happen when explicitly called out in subclass
    DFooRedecorate().gets_overridden()
    print("---")
    # Decorator happens during super call
    DFooNoRedecorateWithSuperCall().gets_overridden()
    print("---")
    # Decorator happens twice: from explicit call out and during super call
    DFooRedecorateWithSuperCall().gets_overridden()
    print("---")
```

Printed output:

```
---
DFooNoRedecorate.gets_overridden
---
hello and up next: calling DFooRedecorate.gets_overridden
DFooRedecorate.gets_overridden
---
hello and up next: calling Foo.gets_overridden
Foo.gets_overridden
DFooNoRedecorateWithSuperCall.gets_overridden
---
hello and up next: calling DFooRedecorateWithSuperCall.gets_overridden
hello and up next: calling Foo.gets_overridden
Foo.gets_overridden
DFooRedecorateWithSuperCall.gets_overridden
---
```